# Proof about valuation function in propositional logic

Tags: logic

Prove that if $S$ is complete and the valuation function $f$ is given by:

$f(p)=1$ if and only if $p \in S$ then for every formula $\alpha$ we have that $\overline f$$(p)=1$ if and only if $\alpha \in S$.

But I think this two valuations are the same if $p \in Var$, but how can I prove this.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Induction on the complexity of formulas in $S$.

Comment: What is that? I dont understand

Comment: Are you using some textbook ?

Comment: This notes: http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~piotrzak/Kechris,%20Lecture%20notes.pdf

Comment: See **1.2.B Induction on Formulas**, page 6.